# How to react after receiving a packet in TCP server

Tags: c#, tcp

I am new in C#. I made a very simple TCP server and TCP Client. I am able to send some message from client to server. If I want see the message which came from client on server I am using button which view the message. Now my stupid question. How make a function which will react on new comming packet from client to view it imediately in textBox? Simple what I want>>> IF comes a new packet......DO SOMETHING.

Comment: [Don't panic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HHGG_UKLP_covers.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a TCP server does this:

1. Create a thread to listen for connection requests
2. Do a TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient in the above thread
3. When AcceptTcpClient accepts a connection, create a new thread
4. In new thread, do a GetStream and then Read the stream.
5. When data arrives, decode it and send a message to the GUI / Controller / whatever.
6. Process the TCP message and send a response message to the TCP thread to Write on the stream the result of the processing.

Comment: When you've got decent async IO, you can do without the thread, but otherwise the principle's the same.